# Is there a difference between getting a Rokinon with MFT mount vs Nikon mount + MFT adapter?

Tags: nikon, lens-adapter, micro-four-thirds, adapter, samyang

I, for now, have a Micro Four Thirds camera and I am considering buying one of the Rokinon/Samyang/Bower lenses (these are all branded clones of same lens).

If you go on Amazon, for each lens, you can choose the option of different mounts - Canon, Nikon, Micro Four Thirds, etc. Obviously, I could buy the MFT, but it occurred to me that I have been thinking about getting a Nikon in a bit, so maybe just buying the Nikon mount and using my Nikon-MFT adapter for now would be a better idea - I could use it on both systems.

So obviously I'd get more flexibility, but would there be any downside to this? From what I can **see**, the lenses themselves are the same, just the mount is changed.

btw price between the 2 mounts is not that big, so I don't care about that. Also price between the different brands sometimes accounts for that, I usually google "samyang rokinon bower chart" and check relative prices, and there hasn't been a big enough variance so far to ever sway me to one mount or other.

Comment: The downside of using adapters is more flare and more play as now it is 2 mounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, aside from the added instability and possible added variance in adapter thickness when stacking adapters, you're correct, but there *are* exceptions.

**Not all the Samyang lenses for mft are identical to their dSLR counterparts.**  Samyang does make  two lenses that were specifically designed for mirrorless mounts and do not work on dSLRs, and they are considerably more compact than dSLR counterparts: the 7.5mm f/3.5 (or in the case of NEX/Fuji X/EOS M 8mm f/2.8) fisheye and the 12mm f/2 wide angle prime.

The 7mm f/3.5 fisheye lens has a completely different optical design than the APS-C dSLR Samyang 8mm f/3.5 fisheye.  While the APS-C version maps stereographically and is dSLR sized, the mirrorless version does the more normal equisolid fisheye mapping, has much better flare control, and in comparison it is tiny:

[image: Samyang dSLR vs.mirrorless fisheyes]

Since most folks get into mirrorless to have a smaller kit, then a smaller native lens obviously has an advantage over the larger adapted lens in terms of being a "better fit" with the system.

Comment: Awesome info, thanks! Now to clarify one thing since I'm new to the term equisolid, and just googled it a bit now - you're saying that if each of these lenses was used on the same MFT camera, the native MFT lens would look more distorted and give a more fisheye look, but the other one would presumably not? (I assume because it's not really using all of the lens)

Comment: @user3833000 Yes. The MFT lens looks more like a "regular" fisheye; the dSLR one is still fishy, but the stereographic mapping looks a little less distorted, and the "cropping" from the smaller four-thirds sensor would remove the most distorted portions of the image at the edges of the frame.